# Real time chat between users like in social network [Laravel + Node + Redis]

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, laravel-5, node.js-connect

I need idea how to make emit and subscribe message between 2 users on secure way.

For example:
`user1` emit `message1` on channel: `user1-2`
`user2` subscribe channel `user1-2` and recive `message1`

How can I be sure `user3` will not intercept chat between `user1` and `user2`?
How can I be sure `user3` will not subscribe channel `user1-2`?

I am using for this Laravel 5, Node.js, Redis, Socket.io.
I just need some idea how to make this secure.

Comment: use "broker server" that pass the messages between users, use authentication in the  server, if user3 register to user1-2 chat he get error simple as that

Comment: Don't understand... Could you show me example?

Comment: how user1 get the messages? from sever the server need to have the logic to allow or disallow someone from getting messages.

Answer (score 0):

User1 ask server for channel name for user1-2, server generates random guid ch-12345 and return it to client and add marks that user1 have reference to ch-12345 and user2 have reference too.

```
SADD user1:channels ch-12345
SADD user2:channels ch-12345
```

User1 post message to ch-12345.

```
ZADD ch-12345 (+new Date()) "Hello!"
```

User2 ask server for available channels when it logged in.

```
SMEMBERS user2:channels
```

OR server notify client that he have new channel.

```
PUBLISH user2-new-channel ch-12345
```

You can easily check if user3 have access to channel by

```
SISMEMBER user3:channels ch-12345
```

And if random guid is big enough you will can not bruteforce a channel name...